# Can Resilient Distributed Datasets be stored as files forever?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, distributed-computing

I would like to store every transformation on RDD as a file so that I can refer them back if needed. 
Every mention of RDDs that I found always talk about them being created in a memory,Can we have them stored on drives or save them as files ?
If yes, a link to an online article describing it how will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

Here just a random a Databricks [link](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/logs_analyzer/chapter3/save_the_rdd_to_files.html) I found:

> RDD's have some built in methods for saving them to disk. Once in files, many of the Hadoop databases can bulk load in data directly from files, as long as they are in a specific format.

Comment: You are welcome @SaugatSaxena! Do not forget to *accept* the answer, if you like (by clicking the green check mark on the left of the answer).